# A way to tell in .NET which part of Excel Formula is evaluating as True

Tags: .net, excel, excel-formula

```
formulaText = (oSheet.Range(ColumnList(oCol.ColumnNumber - 2) & (index).ToString())).Formula
```

The above will get me the formula just fine.
I am parsing this text to learn which columns are acting on this Excel column, and I can do that fine.
But, what if there is a complex structure, such as SUMIF(*expr*, *executeIfTrue*, *executeIfFalse*)

Does anyone know a way to determine only the execution portion of a formula programmtically in .NET?

Since there seems to be a question as to whether this is more about approach, another question I would add is, is there an object I could get from the Excel Cell in which I would work with its properties to learn the nature of the formula (particular expressions used, exact type of formula, etc.?)  This can't be such an obscure, restrictive case that others couldn't benefit from the knowledge.

Comment: I'm suspecting an XY-Problem here (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please see my edit in response to whether my approach in asking this way is poor.

Comment: I don't think is anyway to do this without re-implementing the entire excel formula processor, in Excel, to provide that data.  To say that's a huge undertaking would be quite an understatement.

Comment: ok.  if that is the limitation, I accept.